# Sprite kit SKAction repeatActionForever random wait duration

Tags: sprite-kit

Thank you for helping first.
The `SKAction` sequence looks like this:

```
SKAction *seq = [SKAction sequence:@[wait, throwAnim, run]];
SKAction *req = [SKAction repeatActionForever:seq];
```

Is there any way to make the wait a random duration, or can be controlled during the forever repeat?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [waitForDuration:withRange:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/waitForDuration%3awithRange%3a)

Duration parameter represents average wait time, and range represents variation.

> Each time the action is executed, the action computes a new random
>   value for the duration. The duration may vary in either direction by
>   up to half of the value of the durationRange parameter.

For example if you set duration to 5.0 and range to 2.0 you will get wait times between 4.0 and 6.0